# When accepting a pull request for master and automatically going to develop

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know if when I merge a Hotfix to master if there is any way for this hotfix to also go to develop in a simple way, where I don't need to create 2 pull requests but only 1

Answer (score 0):

> When accepting a pull request for master and automatically going to develop

I am afraid there is no such way to develop in the hotfix branch in a simple way when you merge the Hotfix to master.

When there is no conflict between your hotfix and your master branch, you can merge directly. But the problem is that the hotfix cannot get the recent submissions of the master, and conflicts will occur the next time you merge to the master branch.

To completely avoid this situation, you must either ensure that your master branch is never modified, or that the modified files on the master will not overlap with the files modified by hotfix development.